Azure B2CLogin new account created can't change expired password
I'm working through setting up Azure B2C Login systems.   If I use the SUSI_ user flows, I can create a new user in the UI, get everything set up, and it works.
When I switch to SI Only, and the accounts are created in the portal, I get to the point where I can login, and it says my password is expired.  It then prompts me for a new password.  But when I go to update.   I get:

"Unable to validate the information provided"

Behind the scenes:  Error Code: AADB2C90278
I have the "Force Password Reset" enabled.
I'm just using the standard user flows.  Not customized.
I have set my cell phone, email, etc.  as MFA is a requirement for these accounts.
So what's missing?

can you tell us if you are using "email only" accounts and if you are using app level code like Microsft Identiy Platform.  Are you testing using url test from b2c portal.

Yes to email only.     I've tested it via the test url inside of the portal, and I've got an angular app that I'll be using.
What I have found out is that the legacy user form seems to work, but the recommended forms do not.   I only stumbled across that though.

There is item in each journey called "self service password reset"  allowing a user to initiate the password reset in many scenarios - including sometimes before you are even logged in.  It depends on lots of factors.  It is possible this is relavent to your case and your specific flow journey.  Look for "self-service password reset" or User Initated Password Reset in your journey.

Unfortunately, changing that flag either way doesn't seem to have any effect.
